# Xcode 9.2 doesn't start: Loading a plug-in failed

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, model, xcode9.2

I've a problem running Xcode 9.2. I've just extracted Xcode.xip file and when try to start Xcode, it says:

> Loading a plug-in failed.
>
> The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or
>   damaged and may need to be reinstalled.

Here is the log:

> Shared framework ModelIO.framework not loaded, error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The bundle “ModelIO.framework”
>   couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle’s executable couldn’t be
>   located., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle.,
>   NSBundlePath=/Users/amirrezazadeh/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ModelIO.framework,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “ModelIO.framework” couldn’t be
>   loaded because its executable couldn’t be located.}
>
> Shared framework SceneKit.framework not loaded, error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The bundle “SceneKit.framework”
>   couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle’s executable couldn’t be
>   located., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle.,
>   NSBundlePath=/Users/amirrezazadeh/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/SceneKit.framework,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “SceneKit.framework” couldn’t be
>   loaded because its executable couldn’t be located.}
>
> Shared framework PhysicsKit.framework not loaded, error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The bundle “PhysicsKit.framework”
>   couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle’s executable couldn’t be
>   located., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle.,
>   NSBundlePath=/Users/amirrezazadeh/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “PhysicsKit.framework” couldn’t be
>   loaded because its executable couldn’t be located.}

and more...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I was running MacOs on vmware and tried to extract Xcode.xip file while it was under a shared folder. I just moved Xcode.xip to the guest machine (MacOs) and extracted it and it worked.

I guess it was about either permission or Xcode.xip file path length.